# grails messages enocding does not display german-umlaute

Tags: grails

I am having a peculiar issue. I am running grails (2.3.5). I think I started developping my app with (2.1.x). The issue I am having is with German character encoding (especially Umlaute).

The issue is that in production (ubuntu Linux) the german special characters are not shown correctly in my browser. They are shown by "?". This thing is not happening in my dev (windows maschine). Additionally earlier scaffolded Domain Object (lets say with grails 2.2) are shown correctly even in production. That is what I am not getting. I was comapring the two "show.gsp" checking the encoding (both are utf-8).

Does anybody have a recommendation where to look at?

Comment: Are you using UTF-8 in Database, if the data is coming from DB.UTF-8 in editior or repository if it is hardcoded text in gsp?

Comment: yes I am using utf-8 in the database. But I am not talking about stuff from the database but from the i18n language files.

Answer (score 0):

Add the java propertie -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to your java web-server (tomcat?).